# INSERT VALUES + Max ID

Tags: mysql, sql

```
INSERT INTO newtable (ID) 
VALUES (SELECT MAX( ID)+1 FROM newtable cust) 
SELECT * FROM oldtable WHERE name like 'ItemName%';
```

Hey guys, so basically what i want to do is to get a list from oldtable and add them in the newtable with same values but change only the ID to be +1 in the newtable.. i'm sure this query won't work as i tried but that's what i could go so far ..

Comment: You can't mix VALUES with SELECT.

Comment: Define `id` to be `auto_increment` and let the database handle the incrementing!

Comment: This is a terrible idea!!! Just let MySQL handle the ids with an auto-incrementing PK

Comment: Why do you guys think `AUTO_INCREMENT` is what the OP wants?? 
He's operating with a new table, so the use case seems to be different.

Comment: auto_increment  isn't what i want

Comment: What you want is *not* what you want!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to renumber the IDs in the new table, starting with the max ID value plus one, then you can first get the max id value and put it into a variable:

```
SELECT MAX(id) INTO @maxid FROM oldtable;
```

And after that insert all the ids with the max value added:

```
INSERT INTO newtable (id) 
SELECT id + @maxid + 1 FROM oldtable WHERE name like 'ItemName%';
```

in case if you need other attributes as well:

```
INSERT INTO newtable (id, name, otherattrs) 
SELECT id + @maxid + 1, name, otherattrs FROM oldtable WHERE name like 'ItemName%';
```

---

**Update:** 
if you don't want to explicitly list all the columns, you can achieve the same using with three statements:

```
SELECT MAX(id) INTO @maxid FROM oldtable;

INSERT INTO newtable 
SELECT * FROM oldtable WHERE name like 'ItemName%';

UPDATE newtable SET id = id + @maxid + 1;
```

Comment: INSERT INTO custom_basefullsetcreator (entry, name) 
SELECT entry + @maxid + 1 FROM item_template, name WHERE name like 'Sanctified%';
[Err] 1146 - Table 'world335.name' doesn't exist
Actually selecting name as table isn't correct and also this SQL will just insert entry what i want is to insert other values but just change the entry to be +1

Comment: xD i didn't want to do that :p you have no idea how much columns :D hehe well i think that's the only way just to let you know there is about 100 column or more :D

Comment: By the way do you know any good way that i can use : 
`UPDATE newtable SET id = id + @maxid + 1;` to be like ` UPDATE newtable SET id =  @maxid + 1;` as doing that will be : `Duplicate id '50935' for key 'PRIMARY'' so it should always select maxid from the table and give it +1

Comment: Not sure I understand the question... you can just use this statement as you've written. The `@maxid` variable must be set, of course.